# php replace the src in an image tag

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to dummy proof my website where uses can type information and then publish it. I have the wysiwyg editor disallowing image, but I'm idiot proofing it and if they somehow do post an image I'm trying to replace the src of that image to a default one.

I have tried a few different ways to do this. Currently I have this set up

```
$story = $this->chapter_body = preg_replace('/<img src="(.+)"/Ui', '<img src="<?=base_url();?>"inc/img/noImage.png', $pTag);
```

any help would be wonderful!

Comment: and if they post `<img alt="fooled you!" src="http://disgustingporn.com/haha.jpg">`? Never EVER use regexes to manipulate html. especially html that's probably totally broken/invalid - you're expecting your users to never write mal-formed html, or that they'll never try to game the system.

Comment: Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to manipulate HTML source code, just take a look at some of the related questions and you'll find an answer to yours.

Comment: @MarcB I'm manipulating what they put into the database, not html that is on the page. And the user can't actually enter html into the text editor set up, the editor strips it. I am making sure they cannot paste images into the editor.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro Why would I use DOMDocument over php_replace? I'm not actually manipulating code that is on the page, but what goes into the database.

Comment: @zazvorniki I'm not sure I understand you correctly. You said to MarcB: *the user can't actually enter html into the text editor set up, the editor strips it*; so why don't <img> tags get stripped too?

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro If they entered html, then yes it would strip it. But if they paste in an image from another site, then the editor accepts it. I did figure out what was wrong with my code and it works now. Thank you for all your help.